# Some problem about the frame

Tags: vertical-alignment, box, colorbox, frame

I have made a box and I have a few problems. The first one is that, no matter how I change the toptitle or the bottomtitle, the spacing between the box and the article below is still unchanged.

How can I reduce the spacing between the box and the article?

```
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{Problem}[1][]{%
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    colback=white,
    colbacktitle=white,
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    boxrule=1.25pt,
    titlerule=.2pt,
    toptitle=1.5pt,
    bottomtitle=1.5pt,
    title=Problem~\thetcbcounter,
    #1}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) it is custom here to provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Here there is no document class, preamble or sample body. Please update your question. Additionally, you might want to rephrase your title. It is unclear what `same` should refer to here.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the quick guide in the [`tcolorbox` package documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox):

[image]

you will see that the options for the space before and after the box are `before skip` and `after skip`.

`toptitle` and `bottomtitle` set the space before and after the text of the title.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}% <--- for testing purpose only
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{Problem}[1][]{%
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    colback=white,
    colbacktitle=white,
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    before skip=6pt,
    after skip=6pt,
    boxrule=1.25pt,
    titlerule=.2pt,
    toptitle=1.5pt,
    bottomtitle=1.5pt,
    title=Problem~\thetcbcounter,
    #1}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{Problem}
\blindtext
\end{Problem}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]